# How to display svg file as it is after converting VectorDrawable .xml file

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

How to display svg file as it is after converting VectorDrawable .xml file. My VectorDrawable .xml file is displaying black and white mode.

Comment: Try to convert the svg file to xml with this tool: http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/

Comment: I'd rather recommend this tool http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/